# Magnetization $\ M$ of a ferromagnet as a function of temperature $T$, nearby $T=0$

Tags: condensed-matter, approximations

Using mean-field theory, the magnetization per spin, $M$, for a ferromagnet always obeys the equation:

$M=\frac{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}}{2}\mathrm{tanh} \left( \frac{2}{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}} \frac{T_{\mathrm{c}}}{T} M \right)$

Other than $M$ and $T$, everything is a constant in the above equation.

What I have been trying to do is expand the above function near $T=0$ and find an approximate function $M(T)$.

I am thinking that I should eventually get out Bloch's law, which says that $M(T) = \frac{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}}{2} \left( 1 - \left( \frac{T}{T_{\mathrm{c}}} \right)^{3/2} \right)$. I could be totally wrong though.

I already figured out that for $T$ close to $0$, which corresponds to $\frac{T_{\mathrm{c}}}{T} >> 1 $, the right-hand side of the equation is given by:

$\frac{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}}{2}\mathrm{tanh} \left( \frac{2}{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}} \frac{T_{\mathrm{c}}}{T} M \right) \approx \frac{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}}{2} \left( 1-2e^{ - \frac{4}{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}} \frac{T_{\mathrm{c}}}{T} M } \right) $

Which gives:

$M \approx \frac{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}}{2} \left( 1-2e^{ - \frac{4}{g \mu_{\mathrm{B}}} \frac{T_{\mathrm{c}}}{T} M } \right) $

This doesn't really help me though, because the only way to solve for $M(T)$ now is by making use of a product log function (which I can't for the life of me expand near $T=0$).

Does anyone have any advice? This has been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zeroth order term is $M=g\mu_B/2$. To get the leading correction, you can substitute this on the r.h.s. of your last equation, which gives
$$
M = \tfrac{g\mu_B}{2}(1-2\exp[-\tfrac{2T_c}{T}M])\ .
$$
(This is justified since the effect of any small correction in the exponential will be extremely small for small $T$.)

Note that Bloch's law is derived by using that the magnons present at finite temperature decrease the magnetization, which goes beyond mean-field theory.

Comment: Thank you so much! After some research I found this same result in Kittel's book as well. Much appreciated.